# How to rebuild a screen if confirm is pressed on bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have built a home screen with is rendering cards using `ListView.builder`. These cards have a confirm button which fetches the confirmation status from firestore. When I tap on the `confirm` button, a bottom sheet appears asking whether I am sure. Once I tap `Yes` on the bottom sheet, I want the card on `homepage` to be rebuilt and change the button from `confirm` to `confirm`.

I used the `setState` to change the value at the `onPressed` event and it is successfully changing it but, the confirm button is not changing to `confirmed`.

Any leads on how to solve this issue would be really appreciated.

Homepage cards layout

```
class HomepageCards extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirebaseUser user;
  final Map cardDetails;

  HomepageCards({@required this.user, this.cardDetails});

  @override
  _HomepageCardsState createState() => _HomepageCardsState();
}

class _HomepageCardsState extends State<HomepageCards> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//  Confirmation status from firebase about the captain
    bool isConfirmed = widget.cardDetails['c'];
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(screenHeight / 60, screenHeight / 90,
 // UI Code here......
              Container(
                height: screenHeight / 80,
              ),
//             Confirm Button checking  condition and building UI accordingly
              isConfirmed == true
                  ? captainConfirmed(context, isConfirmed) // if confirmed then different button style widget
                  : confirmAndCancelButton(context, isConfirmed), //if not confirmed then show confirm and cancel button in the card
            ],
          ),
// Some UI
    );
  }
}
```

Once clicking on cancel, the bottom sheet:

```
Widget confirmCaptainBookingBottomSheet(
    BuildContext context, bool isConfirmed) {
  final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Container(
// UI Code
                  Text(
                    'Do you want to confirm?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: black.color,
                      fontSize: headSize.fontSize,
                    ),
                  ),

                        child: FlatButton(
                            child: Text(
                              'YES',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: cyan.color,
                                  fontSize: headSize.fontSize),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              print(isConfirmed);
                              setState(() {
// change the value of is confirmed which is used to build different buttons in the UI as shown in the above code
                                isConfirmed = true;
                              });
                              print(isConfirmed);
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            }),
                      ),
                        child: FlatButton(
                            child: Text(
                              'NO',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: cyan.color,
                                  fontSize: headSize.fontSize),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            }),
                      ),
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function in _HomepageCardsState class which change state of isConfirmed and pass that function to widget where you want change the state. Then on onPressed  of yes just give that function. it will change state of isConfirmed in _HomepageCardsState widget so you can see captainConfirmed widget.

I am leaving small demo which simulates how you can do that in your case.

I hope following code clear your idea.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  bool isConfirmed = false;

  changeconfirmed() {
    setState(() {
      isConfirmed = !isConfirmed;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: Center(
        child: isConfirmed
            ? Home1()
            : Home2(
                function: changeconfirmed,
              ),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class Home1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("confirmed Widget"),
    );
  }
}

class Home2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function function;

  Home2({this.function});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("press"),
      onPressed: function,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Using your answer, I could get into `Home1` but still, the button is not changing i.e. the confirm button is not changing from `confirm` to `confirmed`. It would be great if you could help me in that.

Comment: are you taking about my demo or your real code ? can please elaborate more what you are try to say?